# How to upload kover report into circle ci "Test" tab (dashboard)

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, kover

We have one kotlin multiplatfor project and we are using kover tool for generating test coverage report and we are using circleci pipeline. So I have the config.yml file as shown below:

```
code_coverage:
    <<: *build_config
    steps:
      - checkout
      - *restore_gradle_cache
      - run:
          name: code coverage
          command: ./gradlew koverReport
      - run:
          name: Save test results
          command: |
            mkdir -p ~/test-results/junit/
            find . -type f -regex ".*/build/reports/kover/xml/*.xml" -exec cp {} ~/test-results/junit/ \;
            when: always
      - store_test_results:
          path: ~/test-results
      - *save_gradle_cache
      - store_artifacts:
          path: shared/build/reports/kover/html
      - run:
          name: code coverage minimum value
          command: ./gradlew koverVerify
```

while saving the test result:

> #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail mkdir -p ~/test-results/junit/ find . -type f -regex ".*/build/reports/kover/xml/report.xml" -exec cp {} ~/test-results/junit/ ; when: always /bin/bash: line 2: when::
> command not found
>
> Exited with code exit status 127

And while uploading test result: I am getting following error in CI:

> Archiving the following test results   *
> /home/circleci/test-results/junit/report.xml
>
> failed uploading test results: File:
> home/circleci/test-results/junit/report.xml had the following
> problems:   * invalid top level element: typeIN

The image is shown below:
[image]

What could be the reason, please do help

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the indentation on the `when` key, since it's at the same indentation as what's under the `command` block bash will try to run:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/test-results/junit/
find . -type f -regex ".*/build/reports/kover/xml/*.xml" -exec cp {} ~/test-results/junit/ \;
when: always
```

and fail on the last line, you should be able to fix it be outdenting that line:

```
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ code_coverage:
           command: |
             mkdir -p ~/test-results/junit/
             find . -type f -regex ".*/build/reports/kover/xml/*.xml" -exec cp {} ~/test-results/junit/ \;
-            when: always
+          when: always
       - store_test_results:
           path: ~/test-results
       - store_artifacts:
```